# Laravel maximum execution time error when trying to open .txt file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, fopen

I have a .txt file with countries and their codes and I want to get the contents from it and insert into the database.
But when why try to open the file using the php function fopen() it throws maximum execution time error
here's the code:
web.php:

```
Route::get('/countries', 'PageController@insertCountries');
```

PageController:

```
public function insertCountries()
{
   $file = fopen(asset('databases/countries.txt'), 'r');
    return 'ok';
}
```

The size of the file is 6KB. I am using Laravel 5.4
**EDIT:** the file is in mu public folder in folder databases

Comment: I think if you remove the `asset()` helper it will help. As I see not reason for this file to have a url wrapped round it

Comment: Why don't use `File::get()` ? :)

Comment: Or `database_path()` as you say its in that folder

Comment: `asset` generates the web link to the file, you need to use 'base_path', 'storage_path' or 'database_path' depending on where you store the text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to open local file, use File facade to work directly with filesystem, also you shouldn't use `asset()` helper. So, do something like this instead:

```
$file = File::get('/full/path/to/the/file/countries.txt');
```